# Python, Pandas: How to change the bandwidth selection for DataFrame.plt.density()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, kernel-density

I have some data i have placed into a `pandas` `dataframe`, and I plotted a bar plot of the unique value counts for a particular `column`.

I would like to control the bandwidth of the Pandas built-in `df.plot.density()`

Function, which plots the kde over the data. Is this possible, or am I better off with Sklearn, Scipy, or something else?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some example data, and what your desired result would be compared to what you're getting now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Jan, you could use `seaborn` for this, it's pretty easy to control the bandwidth on a `kde` plot. Here is an example with random normal data:

```
import seaborn as sns

d = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.choice(['a','b','c'], 100), 'y':np.random.randn(100)})

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3)
for name,g in d.groupby('x'):
    g['y'].plot.density(ax=axes[0], label=name)
    sns.kdeplot(g['y'], bw=0.25, ax=axes[1], label=name)
    sns.kdeplot(g['y'], bw=0.75, ax=axes[2], label=name)

axes[0].set_title('pandas plot.density', fontsize='12')
axes[1].set_title('seaborn kde with \n 0.25 bandwidth', fontsize='12')
axes[2].set_title('seaborn kde with \n 0.75 bandwidth', fontsize='12')

plt.legend()
```

This returns the following plot to compare:

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the help, I was trying to avoid seaborn and implement it using sklearn, but I can see why too much manual labor is not desireable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control the bandwidth I would recommend using seaborn's kdeplot (see [link](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html)) - namely the **bw** parameter